# How can I find if a word in a text file also present in another text file?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, while-loop

I have been asked to find whether any of the words in a text file are present in another text file. One of the files contains 10 random words on separate lines which form a 10x10 grid whereas the other file contains 2656 words on separate lines. I need to find if any of the words from the 2656 are a part of any of the 10. It is almost like a word search where I need to compare each of the 2656 words to every line and column of the 10 words in the other text file.

I know how to import the text files and use "try" and "catch" to do so. I am stuck from here. I know that I need to create two loops, one for the rows and one for the columns. I also need to convert each of the 10 lines of words into strings so I can use "String.contains(string)" to compare each of the 2656 words to the 10 lines of words to see if they match. The 10 words can be thought of a grid where it is 10x10.

An example of the 10 words might be:

```
fndgsdgawe
fjshellofj
fslkdfmkls
sfmkbyefkf
fsmflsfmkl
sfmJavadfm
smfjknmfkj
gjforloopj
mgfslgmlgs
gsnmgkjnsg
```

An example of the 2656 words might be:

```
Hello
Bye
Java
ForLoop
NestedLoop
```

As the output, I need to do it in the format of:

```
Hello: row 1, position 3
```

The "matching word" will be the word that matches in both files, the row number will correspond to the row of the 10x10 grid of words that it's found in and the same with the position which can be thought of as the column. Both the row and position start from index 0. I need to use trim() to remove trailing and leading spaces and all occurrences that happen more than once need to be output on a separate line. I am very new at coding and understand the logic behind working it out but I am unable to write it. Can you please help a beginner out? Thanks!

Comment: Can the words be across multiple lines (so contain line breaks `\n`) and can you please share the code you already have?

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp You mean as in the words in the 10x10 grid? The words can only be matched in a vertical column from top to bottom or from left to right. There are no matches for diagonals. I would love to include some code but I have no idea where to start, I'm a beginner. Any help would be so appreciated!

Comment: Are you allowed to use regular expressions?

Comment: @Abra Preferably not